# Error: extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr

Tags: tables, errors

I am using the [ACM SIG template](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates) and trying to create a table of 4 columns.

I get the error mentioned in the title of the question. I know the standard reasons why this error can occur.

But my question is: Is it possible that the template or `.cls` file is controlling the maximum number of columns in a table ? If it were, would I get a different error than this?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The error can be reproduced by

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
one & two & three \\
\hline
one & two 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The problem is caused by the extra column you try to insert. The tabular environment expects two columns but three is inserted.

Comment: that's precisely what was happening. in TexShop on mac, the characters for | and l look exactly same.

Answer (score 3):

Not all `extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr` errors are found via Google or Bing. Something as simple as defining a macro with arguments and forgetting the argument before the first `\\` will reproduce the error.

Same thing with `\newcommand`.

e.g.,

```
\def\test#1#2{$\hbox to 4cm{#1}}$}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
Oh & \test{tested}{} & Oh & \test{Oh} \\
   & \test{testing}{} &   & \test{Ohh}{} \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: That is the very same error as in the other cases, because you are trying to typeset 8 columns, but only four are expected.

Comment: @Johannes_B You've been around with TeX for a while now. Could you point me to a relevant piece of information either through tug or any other book or material where the `newcommand` and this error have been co related with one another? .... The error so far, to my understanding points to a very broad concept I wasn't able to find it but just trough trial and error.

Comment: Your definition wants two arguments, in the first row, the last `\test` doesn't have a second and uses what comes next. That means the double backslash gets (partly) eaten up and LaTeX doesn't have the information that the line should be broken. Hence it complains that two many columns are used.

Comment: Try `\test{Wombat}\\ Wombat` or even use `\def\test#1#2{#1\typeout{This is shown in the terminal: #2}}` to see that the double backslash is eaten up completely.

Comment: But @Johannes_B ok, it complains that two many columns are used.... vague to say the least. And if the information out there is vague then it just defeats the purpose. Who wrote or came up with the idea to have the error `extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr` then?

Comment: Ask @DavidCarlisle in chat ;-)

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29664776#29664776

Comment: The error is unrelated to the newcommand, other than the fact  that you have defined it to gobble the `\\ ` so you get the same error as if the `\\ ` was not there. the error comes from tex-the-program so the wording is Professor Knuth's/

Comment: the error message is very precise and tells you exactly how tex recovers. As there was no `\\ ` it sees an extra `&` in the first row so changes it to `\cr` and tries again

Comment: the engine complains only about the `end template` and that's it...... ahh and forbidden control sequence under TeX itself as soon as another argument comes into play..... of course, it follows ConTeXt............. Who? Dr. David Carlisle? The legend? I'll get there when I see him around.

Comment: Have a look at appendix B of `texdoc novices` where the most common error messages are explained.

Comment: Run the following example with texworks, and when the `?` prompt appears, type `h` and press the enter key: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\test#1#2{#1}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
 \test{tested}{}  & \test{Oh} \\
 wombat&
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}
`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle and Johannes alrighty then, then in plain TeX the argument must be in last row. Right? So this is a vicious cycle back to `\cr` .... I'll have a look at `texdoc novices`

Comment: Your problem is not the end of line, your problem is the faulty of `\test`, Compare the following, what do you expect, what do you see? \documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\test#1#2{#1}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
 \test{tested}  & \test{Oh}{} \\
 wombat& Capybara
\end{tabular} 
\end{document}

Comment: @Johannes_B do you know what I see?  but I'm not going by your last example, although I should. But do you want to know what I see? just not even specifying the extra argument but just `#` will suffice. That's what I see, because a macro parameter can't be used in restricted horizontal mode.

Comment: Now i am confused, do we want to talk about this further in chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39808/discussion-between-doed-and-johannes-b).

Comment: ~The error is unrelated to the newcommand, other than the fact that you have defined it to gobble the \\ so you get the same error as if the \\ was not there. the error comes from tex-the-program so the wording is Professor Knuth's/ – David Carlisle May 15 at 11:43`  I agree with it, but to say later that: `lots of places document that error, the standard documentation for tex and latex (the texbook and latex companion) do for example` is not true. @Johannes_B do you REALLY REALLY think I have missed the entries in the dickimaw series? This has nothing to do with the infamous `&`

Answer (score 3):

Another way to get a `! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr` error is to use an *alignment command* (`\centering`, `\raggedleft`, `\raggedright`) in the last row of a `tabular` environment (when using `p{}` formatting, of course).

For example, this code will give an error:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}|}
     A & \centering B \\
    C & D \\    
\end{tabular}
```

But this code will not:

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}|}
     \centering A &  B \\
     \centering C & D \\    
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

We can use the environment `center` to overcome this problem, with the caveat that we will have extra vertical spaces. (needless to say, you may change to `c` column formatting, if you are willing to give up width control ;))

A quick fix for the problem is to add a **zero-width column**, e.g., `p{0pt}`

**Quick fix solution:**

```
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0pt}}
     \centering A &  \centering B &\\
     \raggedleft C & \raggedright D &\\ 
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Hi，I had the same question and googled to this page. At last, I solved this problem by add one more c, the correct case should like below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c}
one & two & three \\
\hline
one & two 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I just copy-pasted a beautiful array from stackoverflow, where it displays great, and I too had to add a ``c`` to make it display in a standard LaTeX system. Not sure what's going on...

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way you can get this error (the error is still that there are too many columns, but if you're as stupid as I am that isn't obvious):

I was using `&&` instead of `&` for some reason. So I had twice as many columns as I thought. I couldn't figure out what was wrong for a long time, because all the answers here said "this error is caused by having too many columns!" and I was like, "I don't have too many columns!".

So if anyone out there shares my `&&` disability, hopefully this answer will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

Another possible reason is using a `\cline{2-3}` with {2-3} defining which columns need to be covered by the line. If you have less columns (here: less than 3) than you define in the `\cline` command, you get this error.

Example with error:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\ \hline
Content           & Content           \\ \cline{2-3} % <-- this causes the error
Content           & Content           \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Example without error:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
\textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\ \hline
Content           & Content           \\ \cline{2-2}
Content           & Content           \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Thank you for suggesting this solution. Could you elaborate a bit, and/or provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your solution?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package: the number of columns is determined by table contents.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{}
One & Two & Three & Four & Five & Six & Seven & Eight & Nine & Ten \\
One & Two & Three & Four & Five & Six & Seven & Eight & Nine & Ten \\
\end{tblr}

\bigskip

\begin{tblr}{hlines,vlines}
One & Two & Three & Four & Five & Six & Seven & Eight & Nine & Ten \\
One & Two & Three & Four & Five & Six & Seven & Eight & Nine & Ten \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For anyone arriving at this error NOT coming from working in a tabular environment, make sure that you aren't using an "&" without escaping it.  E.g. you should be using `Salt \& Pepper` rather than `Salt & Pepper`.