# Problem with tabular

Tags: tables

I've a problem with a tabular.
Here the MVE:

```
\documentclass[A4,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{tabular}{l|l|l|c|c|c|c}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Livello Istruzione}}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Fascia 1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Fascia 2}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Fascia 3}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Fascia 4}}\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{BdM}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{BTV}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{BdM}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{BTV}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{BdM}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{BTV}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{BdM}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{BTV}}\\
\hline
30\% & 40\% & 2\%\\
20\% & 25\%\\
\hline\hline
\end{tabular}
```

I want a tabular like this:

[image]

but latex says "Error: extra allignement..."

Thank you for help!

Comment: your headings `Fascia` ... have 4 multicolumn{2} so 8 columns but you have only specified 7 columns `l|l|l|c|c|c|c`

Comment: The last lines of your code look strange… Are you sure it is complete?

Comment: potential duplicate: [Error: extra alignment tab has been changed to\cr](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37107)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to create the look of the table shown in your screenshot, you should use the `l` column type for all 8 columns of the `tabular` environment. (The code you posted features a mixture of `l` and `c` cells.)

In the header cells, you appear to want to center rather than left-align the cell contents. In the second argument of `\multicolumn`, be sure to specify whether or not `|` ("vertical bar") should appear at the left- or right-hand edges of the column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{8}{l|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{} \\
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{\textbf{Livello Istruzione}}\\
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Fascia 1}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Fascia 2}}  & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Fascia 3}}  & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Fascia 4}}  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{BdM}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{BTV}}  & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{BdM}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{BTV}}  & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{BdM}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{BTV}}  & 
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{BdM}}  & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{BTV}}  \\
\hline
30\% & 40\% & 2\% & & & & & \\
20\% & 25\% &     & & & & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have edited this answer because, with the latest version of `nicematrix` (5.6), we don't need `makecell` any longer here.

---

You can obtain the look of the table in the question with `nicematrix`. With this solution, all the expected rules are drawn with only one key `hvlines`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{NiceTabular}{*{8}{c}}[hvlines]
\Block{1-8}{\textbf{Livello Istruzione}}\\
\Block{1-2}{\textbf{Fascia 1}}  && 
\Block{1-2}{\textbf{Fascia 2}}  && 
\Block{1-2}{\textbf{Fascia 3}}  && 
\Block{1-2}{\textbf{Fascia 4}}  \\
\textbf{BdM}  & \textbf{BTV}  & 
\textbf{BdM}  & \textbf{BTV}  & 
\textbf{BdM}  & \textbf{BTV}  & 
\textbf{BdM}  & \textbf{BTV}  \\
\Block{}{30\% \\ 20\%} & \Block{}{40\%\\20\%} & \Block{}{2\%\\25\%} \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]