# Errors in table latex

Tags: tables

i receive this error building this table in Latex:

```
Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. Error& 11280.9 & 251 & 44.94& &&
```

This is my document:

```
]{MastersDoctoralThesis} % The class file specifying the document structure
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Required for inputting international characters
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Output font encoding for international characters
\usepackage[dvips]{epsfig,psfrag}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font by default
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} % suppress hyphenation *globally*
\sloppy 
\newcommand{\HY}{\hyphenpenalty=25\exhyphenpenalty=25} 
% re-enable hyphenation locally inside "Z" columns
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\HY\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X} 

%\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography} % The filename of the bibliography
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} % Required to generate language-dependent quotes in the bibliography
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\captionsetup{
    justification = centering
}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Pa}{Pa}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[!htbp]
            \centering
            \begin{tabular}{ l c c c c c}
                \toprule
                Source& Ss&  df& MF& F& $Prob>F$&\\
                \hline
                Groups &6254.4  &2  &3127.22 & 69.58 & $9.07728e^-25$& \\
                Error& 11280.9 & 251 & 44.94& &&\\
                Total& 17535.4& 253& &&\\
                \hline
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \caption{ANOVA results.}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Where is the problem? Is it in the number of columns?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please don't post code fragments. Instead, put your fragments into a complete compilable  document that shows the problem.

Comment: You define 6 column but use 7. remove last ampersands in table rows. It seems to superfluous.

Comment: How many `&`s do you have (an `&` is a separation/column skip between *two* columns)? 6. That means you should have 7 columns in your `tabular`, although you've only defined 6 (`l c c c c c`).

Comment: The line `Total& 17535.4& 253& &&\\ ` has the correct number of `&`, so don't remove the last ampersand from it.

Comment: Possible duplicate? [Error: extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37107/134144)

Comment: @Zarko yes, the problem was the extra & at the end of each row! Thank you!

Comment: @BambOo thanks, i changed the question.

Comment: @DJP thank you too for the suggestion, i fixed the problem!

Comment: @Werner yes, definitely. Thank you!!