# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr (tabular, table)

Tags: tables, tabularx

When I add a column to the first table that has no error message, I will get an error message for the second one.

> "Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr."

What is wrong with the second table that has only one more column than the first table?

First table without error:

```
\begin{table}
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{tab:T}
  \begin{tabular}{ccl}
    \toprule
    \verb|#| of Pr & \verb|#| of Cl & Th\\
    \midrule
    A & B & C\\
    E & F & G\\
    I & J & K\\
    M & N & O\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Second table with error:

```
\begin{table}
  \caption{Caption}
  \label{tab:T}
  \begin{tabular}{ccl}
    \toprule
    \verb|#| of Pr & \verb|#| of Cl & Th & Sh\\
    \midrule
    A & B & C & D\\
    E & F & G & H\\
    I & J & K & L\\
    M & N & O & P\\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{ccl}`, you are only setting 3 columns but using 4

Comment: In the second table, `{ccl}` needs to set the alignment for 4 columns instead of 3.

Comment: potential duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37107